# Выборка в sql и вывод нескольких полей

Tags: sql

я в sql пока не очень. Помогите, пожалуйста разобраться и построить выборку правильно. Есть таблица с множеством полей, нужно из этой таблицы выбрать только поля с минимальным значением по типу `like_1 BETWEEN 1 AND 4`, ячейки, которые не входят в свой диапазон оставить пустыми.

```
"SELECT `clerk_id`, `like_1`, `like_2`, `like_3`, `like_4`, `like_5`, `like_6`, `like_7`, `like_8`, `like_9`, `like_10`, `like_11`, `like_12`, `like_13`, `like_14`, `like_15`, `like_16`, `like_17`, `like_18`, `like_19`, `like_20`, `like_21` FROM ".$selected_operator." WHERE like_1 BETWEEN 1 AND 3 OR like_2 = 3 OR like_3 = 2 OR like_4 BETWEEN 7 AND 10 OR like_5 BETWEEN 4 AND 5 OR like_6 BETWEEN 10 AND 15 OR like_7 BETWEEN 4 AND 5 OR like_8 BETWEEN 4 AND 5 OR like_9 BETWEEN 7 AND 10 OR like_10 BETWEEN 5 AND 10 OR like_11 BETWEEN 4 AND 5 OR like_12 BETWEEN 4 AND 5 OR like_13 = 2 OR like_14 BETWEEN 4 AND 5 OR like_15 BETWEEN 4 AND 5 OR like_16 BETWEEN 4 AND 5 OR like_17 BETWEEN 4 AND 5 OR like_18 = 0;";
```

Вот что я накидал, но ведь есть же способы сделать нормально. Буду рад любому совету либо источнику информации где я могу это посмотреть) Заранее спасибо

Comment: В SQL есть только один способ сделать это нормально. Нужно  переделать таблицу, что бы она соответствовала первой нормальной форме (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) т.е. разбить ее на 2 таблицы. в первой будет только clerk_id и возможно еще какие то единичные поля, описывающие его. Во второй таблице будут поля clerk_id, like_num, value. Соответственно данные кладутся отдельными строками. и вот тогда запрос будет `select clerk_id from tab2 where value BETWEEN 4 AND 5`

Comment: все же, буду надеяться, что это не единственный способ

Comment: Язык SQL был создан в расчете на работу с нормализованными данными. Шаг влево, шаг вправо, работа не то что бы не возможна, но дико неудобна и дико грузит систему.

Comment: Я вас понял, спасибо за помощь. Вопрос можно считать закрытым

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос дал @Mike. Он верный. Не правильно построена бд. Спасибо за помощь, пересмотрю строение бд.

> В SQL есть только один способ сделать это нормально. Нужно переделать таблицу, что бы она соответствовала первой нормальной форме (ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/…) т.е. разбить ее на 2 таблицы. в первой будет только clerk_id и возможно еще какие то единичные поля, описывающие его. Во второй таблице будут поля clerk_id, like_num, value. Соответственно данные кладутся отдельными строками. и вот тогда запрос будет select clerk_id from tab2 where value BETWEEN 4 AND 5